How can I read static properties from instanced classes?
I know this question has been asked with other flavours, but I don't find mine... sorry if duplicated.
I have a function that internally uses the Time class and its properties, as deltaTime, for example.
In order to debug my function, I wouldn't like to use the Time class as is, but a derived one, a TimeDebug : Time class, and override the deltaTime property, turning it into something predictable, i.e.:
public class TimeDebug : Time
{
    public static new float deltaTime { get { return 0.2f; } }
}

My function would consume the class as a polymorphic parameter:
void DoSomething(TimeDebug timer)
{
...
...
}

My function could receive a Time or a TimeDebug parameter, depending on "Release mode" or "Debug mode":
DoSomething(new TimerDebug())   // debug mode

DoSomething(new Timer())   // release mode

Now comes the question: The compiler won't let me compile a read access to static member deltaTime, because I do it from an instance of a class. For example, I can't do:
void DoSomething(TimeDebug timer)
{
Debug.Log(timer.deltaTime);   // won't compile!!
}

How can I pass the class parameter so I can read the deltaTime property, no matter if class parameter is Time or TimeDebug?

What's the point of passing in an instance of a class just to get a static property from it? Why not just pass in the deltaTime itself? release ? Time.deltaTime : 0.2f?

This sounds like an XY Problem.  What's the underlying goal which has driven this design in the first place?  If the goal is to have different functionality in debug mode then there may be better options.

Others have already mentioned the fundamental flaw in doing this so I won't go there. I've also seen mention of using Time.captureDeltaTime, though perhaps you may also be interested in Application.targetFrameRate if testing at a set frame rate is your goal.

@ipodtouch0218 I was trying to avoid branching code, no matter if precompiled or not (@David),. Having branches of code for each "exception" seemed cluttery to me. I thought inheritance could add more simplicity, because we use the same function code (no branching) working with both classes, thanks to polymorphism. Is perhaps polymorphism unadvisable?

You can't override a static property, since static properties cannot be virtual. Best you can do is make a new class that has a non-static virtual float deltaTime property of its own, and make two child classes that inherit from it, one that returns Time.deltaTime, and one that returns 0.2f; then pass in those classes.

@ipodtouch0218 I think yours is the exact solution to the question. My bad for not figuring it... :-) Could you please edit your answer below, and add your recent comment words as part of it? Then, I will mark it as solved.

@oscar done that.

I feel as though this is an XY problem. You don't actually care about "getting a static property through an instance", you're trying to fix the deltaTime to a certain value in Unity (conditionally).
Which can be done by just setting Time.captureDeltaTime to 0.2f:

If this property has a non-zero value then Time.time increases at an interval of captureDeltaTime (scaled by Time.timeScale) regardless of real time and the duration of a frame. This is useful if you want to capture a movie where you need a constant frame rate and want to leave enough time between frames to save screen images.

Obviously, because you're locking the deltaTime without locking the framerate, the game will run WAY too fast for most computers. (1 second realtime at 200fps would be 0.2 (deltaTime) * 200 (frames) = 40 seconds game-time)
As to why it's called "captureDeltaTime"; it's meant mainly for "capturing" a video of gameplay, as fast as possible, with no regards for how it looks in realtime. Kind of how like video editors will scrub through a video way faster than realtime when rendering.

Addressing the "Y" part of the XY problem: you can't override a static property, since static properties cannot be virtual.
Best you can do is make a new class that has a non-static virtual float deltaTime property of its own, and make two child classes that inherit from it, one that returns Time.deltaTime, and one that returns 0.2f; then pass in those classes:
public class Timer {
  public virtual float deltaTime => Time.deltaTime;
}

public class DebugTimer : Timer {
  public override float deltaTime => 0.2f;
}

Then you can just pass in a Timer instance:
void DoSomething(Timer timer)
{
    Debug.Log(timer.deltaTime);
}


Nice hack indeed, did't know it. However, as I am just testing the function, the calls to it happen only inside one frame. Why? Because this way, I have not to wait (for example) 10000 frames to test 10000 function calls. Issuing 10000 function calls inside a simple "for loop" (all inside one frame) is way more efficient. And my TimeDebug class was intended to simulate different frame times (and other parameters) on each call, without exiting the frame. So yes, it is like an XY problem... but I thought inheritance could be an elegant solution to this scenery.

Generalized solution would be to give Time(r) (which one is it?) a virtual non-static property that can be overridden by the derived class:
public class TimeDebug : Time
{
    public static new float deltaTime { get { return 0.2f; } }

    public override float DeltaTime => deltaTime;
}

Mileage on naming-conventions to specify both accesses may wary (it might even be questionable to have the static property at all, depending on your usage), but this is the "correct" way to query a property that is being tied to the specific instance of a class to be queried by methods. Other more arcane implementations might involve giving timer a generalized DeltaTime-property that uses reflection on the "this" reference to lookup the actual value of the static "deltaTime"-property, but I don't really think that makes much sense here.

If you refer to it, the full qualified name of the "Time" class is "UnityEngine.Time" class.
And about your answer, the "DeltaTime" property will be new and won't exist in the base class "Time", AFAIK, so the polymorphism will fail, won't it? If we need to write 2 different functions to access each class, we loose the inheritance advantages
